# Use Javascript to scroll in HTML tables?

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a few table in a scrollbox. Upon loading the page I would like it to automatically scroll to the first empty table row using Javascript. Is this possible?

```
$("table tr").each(function() {        
var cell = $.trim($(this).find('td').text());
if (cell.length == 0){
var el = cell;
el.scrollIntoView(true);
    }
```

Comment: What is means empty table row

Comment: Sure, it's possible. What have YOU tried to make it work and why isn't it working? We are not here to write your code for you.

Comment: It is not scrolling at all. I have about 25 different tables.

Comment: Each table has a few rows. The first column contains a name. The second column is filled in one at a time. I would like the page to always scroll to the first empty table row upon loading the page.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the empty row, you can scroll to it like this.

```
function scrollIntoView(el){
    window.scrollTop( el.offset().top - ($(window).height()/2) );
}
```

Comment: But how do I get the element if the first empty row? Is the code above correct?